# c++ load external classes exe

Tags: c++, ubuntu, game-engine, glut

I'm making a game engine but I appear to have ran into a wall. I want to distribute the game engine as an exe for developers that will then load their files. Internally objects are being stored as:

```
class Gameobject
{
    Vector position;
    virtual void Update(){}
    virtual void Render(){}
}

std::vector<GameObject*> gameobjects;
```

I want the developer to just do

```
class ClassForGame: public GameObject
{
    void Update(){}
    void Render(){}
}
```

and to add to the list

```
gameobjects.push_back(new ClassForGame());
```

but I want them to do this in a seperate file such that the file structure is:
    
 `MyGameEngine.exe` `Game.cpp`

How would I load in their file(s) and their classes in order to use them?

I am using g++, Ubuntu , and glut if that helps I would prefer to not use any external libraries. 
 Also how would they compile their files into my exe so they could distribute their game? I do realize that those are two separate questions.

Comment: Learn more C++ before you do such a project. Right now, you don't seem to know enough about it for other people to actually benefit from your code. In this case: An exe is machine code. A source file is programming language. Programming language can't do anything without a compiler. Also, why did you flag this with Ubuntu and then talk about an exe?

Comment: @Aziuth so people know It's an executable

Answer (score 1):

Engine should be distributed like a library, not like executable file.

Comment: Thank you. Would I use a static library or dynamic library?

Comment: You can use static or dynamic on your choice. It depends of which is better for your project. But like suggested on comment below first of all you should understand difference between them.

Answer (score 0):

firstly, you should learn about process address space, so you can know how a process work.

i think you want to make a SDK of game engine, from which developers call API to make their own project.

a SDK can be released as dll or lib, so you should understand the difference between them.